# Download the File

Tags: rest-api, rest

I have to download the file to  system when an API is occur i am using below
code may i know how to change my code to for download functionality.

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/getPDF/*')
 Global class GETPDF{
 @HttpGet
global static void sendEmail() {
  GeneratePDFController  c = new GeneratePDFController();
  PageReference ref = Page.AccountDetails;
    Blob b = ref.getContentAsPDF();
```

Comment: One simple solution is you can send this pdf to email. SF natively don't provide support for download file. And this is your Web service so i don't think  you can use browser for this.

Comment: You can try return pdf as Blob or convert it to Base64 string.

Comment: Gres can you please provide me the sample code how to edit my controller

Comment: @Gres Imporatant factor is content type here. setting content type to application/octet-stream makes that file downloadable and setting content-disposition with filename gives a name to the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Sathya you can do by below way:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/FileDownloadService/*')
global with sharing class FileDownloadService {
      @HttpGet
      global static void getResponse(){
         RestContext.response.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream');
         RestContext.response.addHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="kiran_machhewarpdf.pdf"');
         PageReference ref = Page.PdfPage;
         Blob pdfBlob = ref.getContentAsPDF();
         RestContext.response.responseBody = pdfBlob;
      }

}
```

Page Code:
[image]
   I have tested this by exposing this on site. 
https://kmforce-developer-edition.ap1.force.com/services/apexrest/FileDownloadService
You can check by using above endpoint. As a common practice mark this as solution if this helps you.

Comment: can you plz post your PDF page code

Comment: @Sathya. There is nothing much in page. In my solution I used renderAs pdf but it will be fine to use normal page getContentAsPDF to get blob. I have updated answer with page code as you asked. I am having very hard time in putting code in Answers. For proper formatting I need to recode here. Thats why I just provided image of page code. Hope this helps you.

Comment: i tested this service from workbench in that case pdf is not downloading ..

Comment: Can you provide any sanpshot about the way you are doing its testing. Also post sample code of your case page and rest service. This helps us to help you.

Comment: i am testing by using below url from workbench /services/apexrest/FileDownloadService

Comment: i am getting status is 200 from workbench but PDF is not downloading

Comment: @Sathya, I don't think you can test it by workbench. First of all let me know whether this service is going to be authenticated or non authenticated? How are you planning to download such rest exposed file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31965/discussion-between-sathya-and-kiran-machhewar).

Comment: @Sathya, As discussed in chat, this will work for downloading files. In order to test the same from other end. I have written a java code which is able to download such file. Here is the code--> https://gist.github.com/kiran-machhewar/a49e946db81d0037fcc9#file-main-java